# XSLT Translation from only one "subclass"?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to take a large XML file and pull only a few tagged elements from it. I thought that I used the template match tag to get into the subclass that I wanted (subClass isn't the right word, but I am coming from this from an RDF/OWL standpoint), but it doesn't seem to filter out the things that are not in that subclass. Here is the code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <ns4:getCollectiveTaskResponse 
xmlns:ns1="http://sample.com/xsd/task/1.0" 
xmlns:ns2="http://sample.com/xsd/commonElements/1.0"     xmlns:ns3="http://sample.com/xsd/individualTask/1.0"     xmlns:ns4="http://sample.com/xsd/collectiveTask/1.0" 
xmlns:ns5="http://sample.com/xsd/handle" 
xmlns:ns6="http://sample.com/appinfo/1">
<ns4:collectiveTask>
    <ns4:generalInformation>
        <number>13</number>
        <title>Quarterback</title>
        <name>Dan Marino</name>

    </ns4:generalInformation>

        <junk>I don't want this</junk>


</ns4:collectiveTask>

        <junk>I don't want this either</junk>
</ns4:getCollectiveTaskResponse>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:ns1="http://sample.com/xsd/task/1.0" 
xmlns:ns2="http://sample.com/xsd/commonElements/1.0"     xmlns:ns3="http://sample.com/xsd/individualTask/1.0"     xmlns:ns4="http://sample.com/xsd/collectiveTask/1.0" 
xmlns:ns5="http://sample.com/xsd/handle" 
xmlns:ns6="http://sample.com/appinfo/1">

<xsl:template     match="/ns4:getCollectiveTaskResponse/ns4:collectiveTask/ns4:generalInformation"    >


Number:<xsl:value-of select="number"/>
Title:<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
Name:<xsl:value-of select="name"/>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not a template matching `/` so XSLT's [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule) kick in. These will effectively match nodes and then select templates for the child nodes. So eventually your `junk` nodes will be selected, and the built-in template will then output text nodes where it files them.

There are a number of ways to solve your particular problem. You can add a template to ignore `junk` nodes...

```
 <xsl:template match="junk" />
```

Or, if you have lots of such nodes, you can add a template to ignore all text nodes

```
<xsl:template match="text()" />
```

Or you could add a template match for `/` and then explicitly select only the node you wanted....

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ns4:getCollectiveTaskResponse/ns4:collectiveTask/ns4:generalInformation" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns4:generalInformation">
Number:<xsl:value-of select="number"/>
Title:<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
Name:<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm inclined to prefer your third option for the OP's case of selecting a small number of items out of a large input document.

Comment: I tried to do the third option (kept the namespaces and used the code) but was unable to get anything beyond "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>". Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: As soon as http://xsltransform.net/ is back-up, I can post a link to show it in action....

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex3

This is the place where I try out xsl stuff on the fly (since it is quicker than command line)

Comment: See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zDV. When available, xsltransform.net is a much better place to try out XSLT.